# Delete Records from table on the basis of inner join

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-delete

I have two tables in oracle DB called **collection** and **collection_h**. I have to delete all the records from **collection_h** which has the same below fields in the **collection** table.

I have to delete all the records from collection_h table that comes out as a result of the below query:

```
select * from collection inner join collection_h on
collection.pos_protocol_id  = collection_h.pos_protocol_id and
collection.terminal_pos_number = collection_h.terminal_pos_number and
collection.cb_file_number = collection_h.cb_file_number and
collection.cb_block_number = collection_h.cb_block_number and
collection.is_stan_batch = collection_h.is_stan_batch and
collection.is_transaction_date = collection_h.is_transaction_date and
collection.is_stan_trans = collection_h.is_stan_trans;
```

Comment: Please only tag the RDBMS you are really using.

Comment: *which has the same below fields* - PK value in collection_H is same as in collection ?

Comment: @CaiusJard yes both tables has the same exact structure including the PKs.

Comment: Simplest is typically `DELETE FROM x WHERE x.pk IN (SELECT x.pk FROM x INNER JOIN y ON...)`

Comment: Oracle is atypical compared to many other DB in this regard, in that it can do `WHERE (x.pk1, x.pk2) IN (SELECT x.pk1, x.pk2...)` if the pk is compound

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete where exists

```
delete
from collection as c
where exists (
  select 1
  from collection_h as h
  where h.pos_protocol_id  = c.pos_protocol_id
    and h.terminal_pos_number = c.terminal_pos_number 
    and h.cb_file_number = c.cb_file_number 
    and h.cb_block_number = c.cb_block_number 
    and h.is_stan_batch = c.is_stan_batch  
    and h.is_transaction_date = c.is_transaction_date
    and h.is_stan_trans = c.is_stan_trans
);
```

Simplified test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=03201839821042e9d1866c0af74c4f2a)*

But if the columns can have NULL's in the matching rows

```
delete
from collection as c
where exists (
  select 1
  from collection_h as h
  where decode(h.pos_protocol_id, c.pos_protocol_id, 0, 1) = 0
    and decode(h.terminal_pos_number, c.terminal_pos_number, 0, 1) = 0 
    and decode(h.cb_file_number, c.cb_file_number, 0, 1) = 0
    and decode(h.cb_block_number, c.cb_block_number, 0, 1) = 0
    and decode(h.is_stan_batch, c.is_stan_batch, 0, 1) = 0
    and decode(h.is_transaction_date, c.is_transaction_date, 0, 1) = 0
    and decode(h.is_stan_trans, c.is_stan_trans, 0, 1) = 0
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Delete x from collection X inner join collection_h Y on
X.pos_protocol_id  = Y.pos_protocol_id and
X.terminal_pos_number = Y.terminal_pos_number and
X.cb_file_number = Y.cb_file_number and
X.cb_block_number = Y.cb_block_number and
X.is_stan_batch = Y.is_stan_batch and
X.is_transaction_date = Y.is_transaction_date and
X.is_stan_trans = Y.is_stan_trans;
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your answer to explain why this should fix the issue ?